# CREATE DSN on an UNIX application server to connect Oracle Server

Tags: java, oracle, dsn

I am trying to connect to database using Java. In my Java code I am hardcoding my username and password to connect to the database.

So I want to avoid hard coding the password. So I am thinking of creating a DSN in Unix for Oracle and then use that DSN in java. My database is sitting in a different server and my java code is sitting in an application server and I only have oracle client installed on the application server.

I want to know is there any way that we can create a DSN on an application server which can be used to connect to database server.

Appreciate your inputs here.

Thanks,
MK.

Comment: Why not use a properties file?

Comment: Yes agree, But I was trying to know how it works with the DSN.